# Do prime numbers satisfy this?

Tags: prime-numbers

Is this true that $n\log\left(\frac{p_n}{p_{n+1}}\right)$ is bounded, where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number?

Comment: what do you mean by $p_n$ is prime number $n$?

Comment: I mean $p_n$ is the nth prime number.

Comment: Try $p_n \sim n \log n$.

Comment: Also $\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n} \to 1$, but this is probably overkill.

Comment: @lhf: $p_n=n\log(n)+O(n\log(\log(n)))$. Trying to estimate the gap between primes using $n\log(n)$ seems too weak here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems unbounded:

Let  $g_n = p_{n+1} - p_n$ be the prime gap, then Westzynthius's result (see link below) states that $\lim\sup \left[ g_n/(\log p_n) \right] = \infty$, hence

$$\lim \sup n \log(p_{n+1}/p_n) = \lim \sup n \log (1 + g_n/p_n) = \lim \sup n g_n/ p
 _n =  \lim \sup  g_n/\log n = \infty$$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture

Comment: @DietrichBurde: they are negatives of each other. If one is bounded, so is the other.

Comment: @PA6OTA: although still a conjecture, this is probably as close as we can get now. (+1)

Comment: @robjohn I think I fixed it

Comment: @PA6OTA: ah, that does show divergence.

Answer (score -2):

$\frac{p_n}{p_{n+1}}<1$ for all $n$, so when $n\to\infty$, $(\frac{p_n}{p_{n+1}})^n\to0$.
so
$$n\log(\frac{p_n}{p_{n+1}})=\log(\frac{p_n}{p_{n+1}})^n\to-\infty$$
so this is not bounded

Comment: -1 because $\lim (p_n/p_{n+1})^n \ne 0$. Probably does not exist

Comment: And also because this is false reasoning... if $x_n \in [0,1[$ satisfies $x_n \to x \in [0,1[$, then $y_n = \sqrt[n]{x_n}$ satisfies $0 \le y_n < 1$ and $y_n^n \to x$. So this reasoning is not sufficient to show $(p_n/p_{n+1})^n \to 0$.